# Performing logic on input attribute

Tags: html, angularjs

Is there a way to perform checks on input attributes like you can for forms?
https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

I'm trying to get the "Enter a small number" text to appear if a number larger than max was typed

```
<div class="ui input right labeled">
              <input type="number"
                  placeholder="{{ vm.object.objectTitle }}"
                  step="any"
                  min="1"
                  max="1000"
                  ng-model="vm.object.model"
                  ng-change="vm.inputChanged()"
                  name="inputFieldName">
            </div>
            <div ng-if="inputFieldName.$error.max"
                 style="color:red">
              Enter a smaller number
            </div>
```

Comment: Potential duplicate of [Angular min and max validators for input\[type='number'\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775330/angular-min-and-max-validators-for-inputtype-number)

Comment: You are checking the wrong docs. This code is AngularJS, and the link is for Angular Framework. Try with this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D